# How to get text from input of widget from screen, which has this widget as build function element?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following situation: there's a part of code of one of my app's screen:

```
class StartFillInfoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StartFillInfoScreenState createState() => _StartFillInfoScreenState();
}

class _StartFillInfoScreenState extends State {
  InputGoalWidget _nameWidget;
  InputGoalWidget _calorieWidget;
  InputGoalWidget _stepsWidget;
  InputGoalWidget _waterWidget;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _nameWidget = InputGoalWidget(title: "What is your name?", emoji: EmojiPack.man);
    _calorieWidget = InputGoalWidget(title: "What is your calorie goal?", emoji: EmojiPack.pizza);
    _stepsWidget = InputGoalWidget(title: "What is your steps goal?", emoji: EmojiPack.shoe);
    _waterWidget = InputGoalWidget(title: "What is your water goal?", emoji: EmojiPack.droplet);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(AppColors.layoutBackgroundColor),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          buildGoalInputs(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Column buildGoalInputs() {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[_nameWidget, _calorieWidget, _stepsWidget, _waterWidget]);
  }

}
```

As you can see, here I create 4 `InputGoalWidget`. Each of them has its own `TextField`. And I also have a button on this screen, after clicking on which I want to get data from `TextField` in `InputGoalWidget`. Here's the code of my widget:

```
class InputGoalWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String emoji;
  String inputData;

  InputGoalWidget({this.title, this.emoji});

  @override
  _InputGoalWidgetState createState() => _InputGoalWidgetState();
}

class _InputGoalWidgetState extends State<InputGoalWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.15,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 16),
            child: Text(
              widget.emoji,
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24.0, bottom: 8.0),
                child: Text(widget.title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ),
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.09,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (_inputData) => widget.inputData = _inputData,
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I added `String inputData` to `InputGoalWidget`, but not to its state. And from my screen I get this variable as

```
_nameWidget.inputData, _calorieWidget.inputData, _stepsWidget.inputData, _waterWidget.inputData
```

But I don't think that this is the best way how I should do it. So, can you explain, how should I prettify my code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your widget code to this:

```
class InputGoalWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String emoji;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  InputGoalWidget({this.title, this.emoji, this.controller});

  @override
  _InputGoalWidgetState createState() => _InputGoalWidgetState();
}
```

Then in the build method of your `InputGoalWidget`:

```
      Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.09,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                child: TextField(
                  controller: widget.controller,
                ),
              )
```

Now in your screen's code:

```
  InputGoalWidget _nameWidget;
  InputGoalWidget _calorieWidget;
  InputGoalWidget _stepsWidget;
  InputGoalWidget _waterWidget;
  Controller nameInputController;
  //Three more controllers for 3 remaining inputGoalWidgets
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _nameWidget = InputGoalWidget(title: "What is your name?", emoji: EmojiPack.man, controller: nameInputController);
    // similarly for other three widgets
  }
```

Now when you want to access the value of suppose _nameWidget then just use:
`nameController.text`

Answer (score 0):

Storing mutable data inside your widget is a bad practice. Widget state can be attached to another widget instance, which will cause unpredictable behaviour.

I see two options for this case:
 1. pass a callback function to `InputGoalWidget` and call it from `TextField.onChanged`
 2. pass a `TextEditingController` to `InputGoalWidget`, and set it to `TextField.controller`

In both cases you can simplify `InputGoalWidget` by making it a `StatelessWidget`